# Destructor not called when returning a local instance

Tags: c++, return, destructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the destructor not called for the returned object from the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697868/why-is-the-destructor-not-called-for-the-returned-object-from-the-function)

I wrote some C++ code (below), compiled it with GCC 4.6 and it ran successfully. But I don't know why the destructor of `classA` isn't called when returning from `createA()`.

Since `ca` is a local variable  in `createA()` (i.e. on the stack), I think its destructor should be called when returning from the function. But in fact, the destructor is only called once when returning from the `main` function.

Moreover, returning a local instance always works fine in this test. I wonder if it's safe to return a local instance on a stack frame when the frame has been popped out after returning.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class classA
{
public:
    classA() { len = 0; v = 0; }

    classA(int a)
    {
        len = a;
        v = new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            v[i] = 2*i;
    }

    ~classA()
    {
        if (v)
            {
            memset(v, 0, len * sizeof(int));
            delete [] v;
        }
    }

    int *v;
    int len;
};

classA createA(int a)
{
    classA ca(a);
    return ca;
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    classA ca = createA(a);
    classA *pca = &ca;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        cout << pca->v[i];
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called **return value optimization**.

In short, the compiler doesn't have to return a copy of the object to optimize the code.

> For ca is a local variable, i.e. on the stack [...]

Not necessarily. `ca` can be created directly in the calling context to prevent the extra copy. **Copy elision** is the only optimization that a compiler is free to perform that can alter expected behavior.

Comment: It also goes under the more general name: copy elision.

Comment: Actually, this is a special case of RVO, called *Named* Return Value Optimization.

Comment: Thanks Grigore. And I've another question: if it's safe to return a local class variable. Is this technique, RVO, a C++ spec or just a compiler optimization trick?

Comment: @CookSchelling it's perfectly safe. It would be unsafe if you returned by reference.

Comment: Hi Grigore. if I pass a class instance to a function. would Copy elision happen?

Comment: @Samuel depends. If you pass a temporary, it could happen. But in general, to prevent the copy, you pass by reference (or `const` reference).

Comment: Hi Grigore, What does the  temporary mean? Do you mean that if i don't change the class instance in the function, it's a TEMP.Otherwise it's not.

Comment: @Samuel no. I mean something like `void foo(A a) {}` and call it with `foo(A())`.